# NHibernate delete entity - check for references

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reference

Is there a generic solution to check for references when the user will delete an entity and it could not be deleted because there are references to it?
I search a solution which works in all situation. The user try to delete, I can check in my DataAccess-Layer and give the user a message "Entity could not be deleted because there are references". How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you don't need to know what references are, you can catch the FK exception in you DAL, and wrap it to your Service layer into a ReferencedObjectsException, with appropriate error message.

Otherwise, you would have to look at the mappings (by code), determine the references (by code), and check for dependencies (by code).

Rhino.Security has a Mapping rewriting part here : https://github.com/ayende/rhino-security/blob/master/Rhino.Security/Impl/MappingRewriting/UserMapper.cs, from the NHibernate configuration object, you have access to the Class Mappings.

Comment: is there an example, how I can look at the mappings and determine the references by code?

Comment: updated my answer. you should be able to work something out from given link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the related entities and include the `cascade='all-delete-orphan'` option.

Comment: Not always a good idea. Suppose you have Questions with Tags. User mistakenly delete a Tag, and gone are your Questions.

Comment: If you have a many to many join entity on a `Question-Tag` join table, that entity should be deleted with the deletion of the `Question` or the `Tag`, but the mapping should not indicate that the `Tag` or the `Question `should be deleted when the `Question-Tag` is deleted.

Comment: Ok, suppose you can only have 1 tag per question. When the tag is deleted, if you cascade the delete, all associated questions are deleted too.

Comment: I don't know why you'd set up a foreign key relationship in that case, but yeah, that would be an area where you wouldn't want to do a `'all-delete-orphan'`. You'd instead want to map the `<many-to-one>` for the Tag property of the question with a `not-found='ignore'`.

Comment: Nope, I was just saying that sometimes, when you delete an entity, you should not cascade the delete, as it may wipe half your database :D

Comment: I play by this rule: if you only use Foreign Key constraints as intended - where a row should not exist/is unintelligible without the related row, then you can use `'all-delete-orphan'` wherever you have a Foreign Key.